# VSCode Intellisense TypeScript: Exclude path that is referenced in paths

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, path, intellisense

I work on an Angular application, with some of the code grouped into their own (npm) projects so they can be referenced by other applications.

When I write code within the `app` folder, VSCode's Intellisense suggests the following paths for auto-imports, both of which work:

```
import 'FooComponent' from module "../../../projects/company/shared/src/foo/foo.component";
import 'FooComponent' from module "@company/shared";
```

**My goal is to make the `"@company/shared"` import the default choice.** It would be even better if the relative path could be hidden completely. I have tried this so far:

1. `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier: non-relative`
2. `typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding: minimal`
3. Excluding the directory in tsconfig.json after specifying the paths.

So far, these have not solved my problem.

I have an Angular project structure similar to this:

```
ApplicationName
  - dist
  - e2e
  - node_modules
  - projects
    - company
      - domain
      - shared
  - src
    - app
  tsconfig.json
```

Within `tsconfig.json`, I reference the `shared` project in the `paths`:

```
{ 
  "compilerOptions": {
    // standard stuff
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      @company/domain: [
        ../projects/company/domain/src/public-api
      ],
      @company/shared: [
        ../projects/company/shared/src/public-api
      ]
    },
    "exclude": [
      "./dist/**,",
      "**/projects/company"
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to hide the long `"../../../projects/company/shared/src/foo/foo.component"` import suggestion? It hogs the default and adds noise when there are multiple autocomplete-suggestions for `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to remove all the typescript import extension (auto import, typescript hero, typescript importer), then changing my : typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier from relative to project-relative.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I removed the TypeScript Importer extension and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

`"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "project-relative"`

to `settings.json` in vscode worked for me.

I had to restart the TS Server for it to show up. (Command Palette --> `Typescript: Restart TS Server`.)

Now the default import suggestion is `@company/packageName`, which is what I wanted.